# Compare 2 Excel Sheets through ID and copy differences and missing datas

Tags: excel, vba, copy, compare, difference

I have two Excel files and I need to compare two excels based on "ID"+(Other columns)". I need different values on both sides and missing values column by column in sepaerated Excel sheets/files for every compare.

I need to see what data change in which side, which difference is exist on which side.

Please find a sample output;

**Sheet1:**

```
 ID    BranchID   Name
 7790     2   
 7792     2
 77793    1
 7794     1
 77795    1        0
 7796     100
```

**Sheet2:**

```
ID  BRANCHID    NAME
7790    2   
7790    2   
7792    2   
7793    100     0
7794    1   
7795    100     Name
7796    2
```

**Result1:**

```
ID  BRANCHID    ID1 BRANCHID1
7790    2      7790       2
0       0      7790       2
7792    2      7792       2
7793    1      0          0
0       0      7793      100
7794    1      7794      1
7795    1      0          0
0       0      7795      100
0       0      7796       2
7796    100    0          0
```

**Result2:**

```
ID    NAME  ID1     NAME1
7790        7790    
0           7790    
7792        7792    
7793        0   
0           7793     0
7794        7794    
7795   0    0   
0           7795     Name
7796        7796
```

Could you please help with an excel macro VBA?

Comment: Why a macro when a simple Excel function in a helper column or two can provide the same result a lot easier?

Comment: Can you write the formulas for my sample sheets? I need results like i mentioned in my messages. This type of format may not be possible with formulas.

Comment: You can have a try yourself, and then we can help with specific issues - SO is not a code writing service. As a hint, consider `=IF(...)`, equality between cells and `ISBLANK` as a starting point.

Comment: It's not clear exactly what the rules are for the comparison, so it would help you get answers if you could provide a detailed explanation of how the result sheets are compiled.  Don't make us guess...